# OpenGL: Copy irregular (non square) portion of source FBO to destination FBO

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fbo

Im doing 2D rendering and I'm using FBOs. I need to copy irregular (non square) portion of source FBO to destination FBO.

Is there a way to achieve that by applying some mask?

What I'm doing now:

1. Copy part of main FBO to temp FBO.
2. Do some drawing on temp FBO.
3. glBlitFramebuffer temp FBO back to main FBO stretched.

So, as simplest example, i would like to take round part (or polygon) from main fbo do some drawings on it and blit it back stretched to main FBO. It is like round (or polygonal) magnification glass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a stencil mask. See this example from the OpenGL wiki: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Stencil_Mask

Comment: I have tried that but I had no success. It might be I was doing that wrong. Are you sure that should work with FBOs?

Comment: How are you copying the FBO, by the way? The stencil test does not apply to something like `glBlitFramebuffer (...)`. You will need to draw something like a full-screen quad that stretches the color/depth buffer over the viewport in order to do this.

Comment: I have updated question to provide more details. Thanks all of you.

Comment: There's no way to do it with `glBlitFramebuffer`. You must do what Andon said and render a fullscreen quad over the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for update. It seems thats the way to do it.
If you re-read my updated question, what are the steps to achieve that?

Comment: Attach a texture to to the color attachment of the temp FBO. After rendering to the temp FBO, bind that texture, set up a shader to sample from it, then draw a quad over the screen to 'copy' the data. To draw the quad, just draw a box with corners at <-1,-1> and <1,1> and don't do any transformations.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. But how i define area to be "magnified"? I mean area to be stretched?

Comment: You'll have to sample it differently in your copying shader. That's beyond of the scope of rendering to a non-rectangular viewport.

Comment: Ok, it seems I'm out of the scope so  I'll have to rephhrase my question. I'll acept this answer if I find a solution in new question. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer actually works. Tutorial was missing a call to 
...
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
...
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, though the tutorial does leave out that you should also clear the stencil buffer each frame.

Comment: It was necessary. My first attempt failed because I wasn't gave isntructions what to do (glStencilOp).